# Timezone BST has wrong offset

Tags: java, timezone, java-time, datetime-parsing, zoneddatetime

Cannot understand why BST (UTC Offset: UTC +1) got offset +11 in following code. I would expect +1.

```java
final String lastUpdated = "Mon Sep 27 18:29:00 BST 2021";
final DateTimeFormatter LAST_UPDATED_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z y").withLocale(Locale.UK);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(lastUpdated, LAST_UPDATED_FORMATTER);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime();
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.getOffset()); // +11:00; expected +1
System.out.println(localDateTime.toString());
```

Console output:

```
+11:00
2021-09-27T07:29
```

All is clear once is date in UTC:

```
final String lastUpdated = "Mon Sep 27 18:29:00 BST 2021";
```

Comment: You could add the line `System.out.println(zonedDateTime.getZone().toString());`, execute the code and watch the output. Hint: `BST` is **not interpreted** as British Summer Time in this case!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's what you get for using ambiguous abbreviations, I'm afraid. BST can mean different things, as shown [here](https://24timezones.com/time-zone/bst).

It looks like in this case it's being interpreted as Bougainville Standard Time, which is indeed UTC+11.

(Even within the UK, BST hasn't always meant British Summer Time. Between 1968 and 1971, BST meant "British Standard Time", although it was still GMT+1.)

Using abbreviations is "somewhat okay" for *formatting*, but should be avoided for *parsing* purposes where at all possible. If you're receiving data that you *know* will use it, and you know what it should mean, you're probably best off replacing it in the text before parsing.